# editable table cell in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.actualweight', function(e) {

    if (!$('.thVal1', this).length)

        $(this).html(function(i, v) {
        return '<input class="thVal1" type="text" value="' + v + '" />'
        $(".thVal1").focus();

    });
}).on({
    // bind keyup event
    'keyup': function(event) {

        // on enter key update the content
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $(this).parent().html($(this).val().trim());
        }
    },
    'blur': function() {
        actualweight = $(".thVal1").val();
        // if focus out the element update the content with iput value
        $(this).parent().html($(this).val().trim());
    }
}, '.thVal1');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When I click on td TextBox gets displayed. If I click again text gets focus. However, TextBox should get focus on the first click only.

Comment: put your html and css code also.

Comment: I want to edit this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you put code after a `return` statement?

I think you should change it to

```
$(this).html(function(i, v) {
  return '<input class="thVal1" type="text" value="' + v + '" />'
  //$('.thVal1').focus();
});
$('.thVal1').focus();
```